# Modern ways to print pdf's in Java

Tags: pdf, xslt

Hello I am doing a study for my university, mainly I am focusing on how are companies printing from code (example java) pdf's today. I know some companies are still using XSL + XML because it's easier in my opinion (different project from apache).

But is XSL still fast and reliable  when we want to do a modification in a page ?

In the practical part I am trying to show what XSL is measing and mainly I want to say that there aren't so many (free) software's that can be used by people that don't have knowledge on XSL/XSLT etc.

Comment: An interesting problem, but off-topic for StackOverflow where the focus is programming code issues of the `if/else/endif` variety. Might be more appropriate to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com , but I don't think so, so read their help to post a properly phrased Q. Actually, https://quora.com seems to welcome such open-ended Qs and there are knowledgeable members. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck!

Comment: You'll find a number of papers comparing and contrasting XSL-FO and CSS-for-printing in recent XML conferences such as Markup UK and XML Prague. Note that many publishers are using technologies much older than XML, XSLT, and XSL-FO, and still regard the move to XML+XSL as a step forward from what they are doing today. The bigger the publisher, the older the technology is likely to be.